# JS script causes little shift, how do i prevent it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some form, and if validation failed, Jquery prepends it with error message.
When user clicks on form again, error is faded out, and here is the problem: error fade out causes form to shift up a little bit.
Not like this is big issue, but it really annoys me every time I see it. Tried to fix by playing with CSS and setting different margin-top and so on, nothing helps.
Thank you for advice.

Jquery:

```
$('body').delegate("input#email",'focus',function(){
        $('#errors_of_sign').remove();});

$('body').delegate("input#password",'focus',function(){
        $('#errors_of_sign').remove();});
```

CSS:

```
.sign_in {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 28%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #c1ffc6;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 25%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999999;
    font-size: 14px;


}
.signs_form{

    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right-style: solid;
    padding-right: 10%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #c1ffc6;


}
.fb_sign {

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;


}
#sign_in_fb {
    vertical-align: 100%;

}
```

Comment: You should provide some code

Comment: it is really usual, but ok

Comment: How does the jquery look that fades the error?

Comment: sings_form jerks up a little bit

Comment: I was refering to the code. But i guess thats what you edited. I can see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that when you remove it from DOM it obviously doesn't take up the space anymore. So instead just hide it like this:

```
$('body').delegate("input#email",'focus',function(){
    $('#errors_of_sign').css('visibility','hidden');
})

$('body').delegate("input#password",'focus',function(){
    $('#errors_of_sign').css('visibility','hidden');
})
```

**Edit:**
And also you should use "on" instead of "delegate" if your jquery version is 1.7 or later

Comment: hmmm...with these code nothing happens with error message at all

Comment: whoops sorry, it should be hidden instead of none. I edited my answer.

Comment: yep, that works, also I figured out that with my css setting background color of error to white also do pretty the same)